# Why does this alert() call work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, alert

`alert(/abc/);`

The above line alerts with the message: `/abc/` although I do not use **quotes** around `/abc/`, what's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've constructed a regular expression, and that's what's being shown in the alert message.

In JavaScript, a regular expression literal looks like forward slash characters (`/`) surrounding the expression, and optionally followed by one or more flag characters.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Pointys answer, what you are seeing is the text representation of the regular expression as in

```
var aRegExp = /exp/;
alert( aRegExp.toString() );
```

You can find more uses at http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/using-javascripts-tostring-method